# xlXYScatter is producing xlXYScatterLines when generated by python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, win32com

I am writing code to produce an XY Scatter graph in excel but I can't seem to produce a simple xlXYScatter, instead my programme produces an xlXYScatterLines.

I'm using win32com and have tried using the enumeration number (`-4169`), `win32com.client.constants.xlXYScatter`, and `xlXYScatter` as the `ChartType` but all produce a scatter with lines.
Bellow is my code for making the chart:

```
firstChart = excel.Charts.Add()
firstChart.Name = "VMD vs Modified VMD"
firstChart.ChartType = -4169
firstChart.SetSourceData(firstSheet.Range("$A:$B"))
```

I am using Python 3.3 and excel 2010